# Resize vertical div on drag

Tags: resize

Dragging to change the horizontal block size can be done successfully.
Changing to a vertical block will not succeed.

Horizontal BOX (success): `enter code here`https://codepen.io/Winnie-Liang/pen/rNQRMYW?editors=1010
Vertical BOX (fails): `enter code here`https://codepen.io/Winnie-Liang/pen/VwVNLOo?editors=1010

Can help me find out where is wrong in Vertical BOX resize?

Comment: Please include your code here instead of links as it will change over time. You can read this for more detail https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/17493431